# What does numbers after opcode (Lua bytecode) mean?

Tags: c, lua, bytecode

What do the numbers after `LOADK`, `SETGLOBAL` `CALL`, etc. mean?

```
E:\Project\ZhScheme\lua>luac -l luac.out

    main  (6 instructions, 24 bytes at 004784F8)
    0+ params, 2 slots, 0 upvalues, 0 locals, 4 constants, 0 functions
            1       [1]     LOADK           0 -2    ; 18
            2       [1]     SETGLOBAL       0 -1    ; a
            3       [2]     GETGLOBAL       0 -3    ; print
            4       [2]     LOADK           1 -4    ; "hello world"
            5       [2]     CALL            0 2 1
            6       [2]     RETURN          0 1
```

https://the-ravi-programming-language.readthedocs.io/en/latest/lua_bytecode_reference.html

http://files.catwell.info/misc/mirror/lua-5.2-bytecode-vm-dirk-laurie/lua52vm.html

It seems these numbers point to `18`  and `"hello world"`, but where are these constant stored?

Comment: You mean the operands?

Comment: Each instruction has parameters: A, B, C.  Positive values are VM registers, negative values are constant indices.  To see the constants, try `luac -l -l -p luac.out`.  Or use [colorized luac](https://luac.nl/) which gives some explanations for instruction parameters. Or use [Lua bytecode viewer](https://lua-bytecode.github.io/) which shows description for every command.